# Adding firebase to Codename One

Tags: firebase, codenameone

I am developing my app using the Codename One framework and using Firebase to store my data in the cloud. In order to use all Firebase potential I would like to add it to my app, but since I am not using Android Studio nor Xcode, I don't know how I can do this.

¿do you know if it is even possible to add Firebase to Codename One?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible since the codapps.io mooc did just that using the REST API for firebase. Unfortunately I can't seem to find any of their sources online and the only thing I found was this: [Reading JSON data that begins with [ and ends with ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963380/reading-json-data-that-begins-with-and-ends-with)

Comment: Hi Shai. I also made the REST API work. I can upload and retrieve data and it behaves very well. But when added to the app, Firebase lets your app to be in sync, so that all the data uploaded by a user can be updated to other users in real time. No need to hit the "update" button. I am trying to achieve that in my app.

Comment: In that case you will probably need native integration for that you will need to dig into the complexities covered here: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html

Comment: Is there any chance that you will support firestore nativity? The framework is quite nice to use and most important, we don't need to worry about connections, network switches whatever (it's behaving as a local database when disconnected and syncs later on). The whole Firebase framework, especially functions and the database is just an incredible help for any developer. We would use Codename One if you would support Firebase or at least firestore. It's the future.

Comment: I disagree with most of your statements but the most ridiculous one is: "We would use your framework if...". I believe you honestly think you're truthful with that statement but every single person who made that statement in our 7+ years as a startup hasn't followed up on that. So if you are serious about this, signup as an enterprise account and we'll add that support within two-three months **guaranteed** !