# Firebase in Codename One

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, codenameone

I've been looking for Codename One Tutorials on how to connect to Firebase but I can't find them, Does anyone have any basics on how to connect using Codename One to Firebase?

And if I should JSON, how am I able to connect using it?

Comment: Check out the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113048/adding-firebase-to-codename-one I think it covers most of your question

Comment: It helped  a lot...thanks.