# convert JSONObject to JSONArray error

Tags: java, android, json

Error:

```
W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)

W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)

W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
```

Code :

Inside a try block

```
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data_to_send));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            if(jsonObject.length() == 0)
            {
                retunedContact = null;

            }
            else
            {
                String name,email;
                name = null;
                email=null;

                if(jsonObject.has("name"))
                    name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                if(jsonObject.has("email"))
                    email =jsonObject.getString("email");

                retunedContact = new Contact(name , email , contact.username , contact.password);

            }


        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: The response you are getting from the server is JSON Array? Print your response from the server too

Comment: post your json respone

Comment: please add your json format of Data. that allows us to know why exactly you get stuck at it ..

Comment: clearly, you are parsing it wrong, post the json response, then we can help with the parser

Answer (score 0):

Your result seems to be a `JSONArray` like `[..]` instead of a `JSONObject` like `{..}`

Instead of `JsonObject` use `JsonArray`, i.e. for example like this:

```
try {
    JSONArray myJsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // log Error
}
```

Comment: then i get an error for this code:

cannot reslove method has in 

if(jsonObject.has("name"))
                        name = jsonObject.getString("name");

                   if(jsonObject.has("email"))
                        email =jsonObject.getString("email");

Comment: `JSONArray` objects have a function `getJSONObject(int index)` and you can loop through all of the `JSONObject` by writing a simple for-loop.

Comment: JSONArray jsonObject = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jsonObject.length();i++)
                {

                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                    if (jsonObject.length() == 0) {
                        retunedContact = null;

                    }

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634518/getting-jsonobject-from-jsonarray/7634559#7634559

Answer (score 0):

I think what format you get from the `api` is

```
[
  {
     "somekey":"somevalue",
     "somekey2":"somevalue2"
  },

  {
     "somekey":"somevalue",
     "somekey2":"somevalue2"
  }
]
```

then you should know that this format is a `JSONArray` not a `JSONObject`. So, Better to try either this Code

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser() 
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONArray)parser.parse(result);
```

or

```
try {
    JSONArray obj_JSONArray= new JSONArray(result);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```