# Error "[] cannot be converted to JSON" when trying to create a JSON Object from String

Tags: json, gson, kotlin

I'm using the Koltin language with GSON library to create/parse JSON. I have the following string that represents a JSON object

```
val jsonString = "{ \"age\": 22, \"height\" : 1.8, \"profession\":\"Student\", \"at_room\": false, \"gender\": \"male\",\"pictures\": []}"
```

When I try to convert this string to a JSON Object, by doing

```
val jsonData = JsonParser().parse(jsonString).asJsonObject
```

I get the following error:

`[] can not be converted to JSON`

I guess that this error is due to the fact that `pictures` is a JSONArray and not a primitive type. Anyway, I would like to know how to convert this string to a JSON Object correctly.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: I don't think this deserves to have a Java tag, but don't you need to escape double quotes in your string?

Comment: @Ulises, Kotlin language with Gson lib

Comment: @cricket_007, I checked the JSON [here](http://jsonlint.com/). It's a valid JSON file

Comment: I'm sure the JSON itself is valid, but you have double quotes within double quotes. Unless kotlin handles that somehow, you have to escape the quotes in the string

Comment: There are examples of creating JSON objects here   https://github.com/SalomonBrys/Kotson/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @cricket_007, I'm using this library too :) , but the problem is that this String containing the JSON object is a server response, I'm just storing it in a `val`

Comment: Okay, my only point was that I don't think your simple string in your question here is a valid string object

Comment: It might be caused by the `[]` at the end...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634518/getting-jsonobject-from-jsonarray  this might help

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, there is something else that is failing.

I've tried this and it works.

```
package proves

import com.google.gson.JsonParser

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val jsonString = "{ \"age\": 22, \"height\" : 1.8, \"profession\":\"Student\", \"at_room\": false, \"gender\": \"male\",\"pictures\": []}"
    val jsonData = JsonParser().parse(jsonString).asJsonObject
    print(jsonData)
}
```

Output:

```
{"age":22,"height":1.8,"profession":"Student","at_room":false,"gender":"male","pictures":[]}
```