# How to convert JSON Array to JSON object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, wso2-api-manager

I have a json array. I need to bring this:

```
[
  {"id": ["1"],
   "title": ["hello"],
   "start": ["2016-05-20"],
   "end": ["2016-05-25"],
  }
]
```

to this:

```
[
  {"id": "1",
   "title: "hello",
   "start": "2016-05-20",
   "end": "2016-05-25",
  }
]
```

How to do that?

Comment: duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634518/getting-jsonobject-from-jsonarray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop with [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and assign all properties with the first element.

```js
var array = [{ "id": ["1"], "title": ["hello"], "start": ["2016-05-20"], "end": ["2016-05-25"], }];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        a[k] = a[k][0];
    });
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** and **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**

```js
var data = [{
  "id": ["1"],
  "title": ["hello"],
  "start": ["2016-05-20"],
  "end": ["2016-05-25"],
}];
data.forEach(function(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(v) {
    obj[v] = obj[v][0];
  });
});
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do using `.map` and `for-in` loop

```
var test = [
  {"id": ["1"],
   "title": ["hello"],
   "start": ["2016-05-20"],
   "end": ["2016-05-25"],
  }
]
test.map(function(x){
  for(var key in x){
   x[key] = x[key].join('')
  }
  return x;
});
```