# how get string from an array that is in JSONArray that is in JSONArray in android?

Tags: android, arrays, json

Is there anybody who knows that how can I get the string "num12" from this JSON array in android with JSONObject and JSONArray?

```
[{
"id": 7378,
"status": "publish",    
"acf": {
    "dars": [{
        "title": "math",
        "cat": "cat1",
        "kind": "free",
        "question": "num1"
    },{
        "title": "math2",
        "cat": "cat12",
        "kind": "free",
        "question": "num12"
    }]
}
```

}]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting JSONObject from JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634518/getting-jsonobject-from-jsonarray)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: 1) get the object in which this `num12` key is. 2) get the value itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  public String parseObj(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    int size = jsonArray.length();
    String question = "";
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject obj1 = object.getJSONObject("acf");
            JSONArray array = obj1.getJSONArray("dars");
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject objectInner = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                question = objectInner.getString("question");
            }

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return question;
}
```

Comment: please avoid doing job instead of other people. It makes them much more lazy.

Comment: It is never a bad habit to help anyone stuck between code.

Comment: We are all here for help. But we must teach fishing instead of giving fish.

Comment: @stutikasliwal that is not *help*, you are making people think that they don't have to work hard to be smart, and just need to find someone to do their job instead ofthem.